# Java - Convert HexaDecimal To Decimal

Tags: java, type-conversion, integer, hex

I try to convert `HexDecimal` to Decimal, however when I do it, I don't have correct answer.

This is my code :

```
public class HexToDecimal {

    public static int hex2Decimal(String s) {
        String digits = "0123456789ABCDEF";
        s = s.toUpperCase();
        int val = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char c = s.charAt(i);
            int d = digits.indexOf(c);
            val = 16 * val + d;
        }
        return val;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int decimal = hex2Decimal("1f8271e410bf18b5312aeaaff07854b6");
        System.out.println(decimal);

    }
}
```

Result : `-260549450`

Could you help me?

Comment: The value you are testing with is bigger than the max value of an integer. So even if the logic were correct this wouldn't work for such a big number.

Comment: So, should I convert it to in bigInteger ?

Answer (score 1):

the wanted conversion goes beyond the boundaries of the integer interval, try to use `BigInteger` :

```
public static BigInteger hex2Decimal(String s) {
    String digits = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    s = s.toUpperCase();
    BigInteger sixteen = new BigInteger("16");
    BigInteger bigVal = new BigInteger("0");
  //  int val = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        int d = digits.indexOf(c);
        BigInteger bigD = new BigInteger(String.valueOf(d));

        bigVal = (bigVal.multiply(sixteen)).add(bigD);
      //  val = 16 * val + d;
    }
    // return val;
    return bigVal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It not work because your Number is too big, and the max value of Integer is `2147483647` :

Use `BigInteger` instead :

```
BigInteger hex = new BigInteger("1f8271e410bf18b5312aeaaff07854b6", 16);
```

**Result**

```
41883376442430967210640944342039549110
```